# Socket io is polling, sends

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My socket.js file that loads socket.io, redis and a few other things. I am running the socket with node socket.js my webrowser is the latest google chrome

```
var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('new-order-created');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message){

    console.log(channel, message);

    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);

});

server.listen(8090, function(){
    console.log("Listening on " + 8090);
});
```

The socket loads fine as you can see

[image]

I am trying to listen via my html page here:

```
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8090');

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $( "#messages" ).append( "<p>"+data.user+" : "+data.message+"</p>" );
    });

</script>
```

My respnses are different like so:

```
97:0{"sid":"08zS_Xm5X8wafIUgACHG","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}2:40
```

Any idea how to fix, or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The client is listening to the wrong event, namely `message`, which is the low-level "event name" between the server and the client. The data you're seeing is the raw payload data (documented [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol#payload)).

The server is emitting a different type of event (its name being what `channel + ':' + message.event` evaluates to), which is the one that the client should be listening for.

Comment: I've changed the on, but am stilling getting the same: https://i.imgur.com/0k76nxD.png and the events: https://i.imgur.com/l7vSx7P.png

Comment: Nevermind... turns out my socket.io.js cdn file was an older version